# How do I generate QFoo classes for the typesafe query system in DataNucleus JDO implementation?

Tags: groovy, code-generation, jdo, datanucleus

I've created a maven module called **Domain**. In this module, I have all of my entity classes for my database written in Groovy. Up until this current problem, this configuration has been working quite well.

As per [the directions on the DataNucleus page](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/jdoql_typesafe.html), I have setup my maven pom as shown below. My entity classes enhance just fine and I can use them for all of the normal old-fashioned Query APIs. However, I don't have *QProduct* style code-generated classes like the documentation claims will be created for me. Does anyone know what I have to do to get these classes generated?

Edit: I forgot to mention that I **only** have the 1.6 jdk installed on the box and I have the necessary bits set on Maven for a 1.6 source and target.

```
    <dependencies>
        <!-- JDO Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
            <version>[2.9, )</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
            <version>[2.9, )</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-jdo-query</artifactId>
            <version>[2.9, )</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
            <version>[3.0, 4.0)</version>
        </dependency>
   </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/groovy</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <!-- This plugin does compile time enhancement of the entity classes using
                 bytecode weaving -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-release</version>
                <configuration>
                    <metadataIncludes>**/entities/*.class</metadataIncludes>
                    <generateConstructor>true</generateConstructor>
                    <enhancerName>ASM</enhancerName>
                    <quiet>true</quiet>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enhance-classes</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JDK1.6+, since that will invoke any annotation processors found in the CLASSPATH. Works for everyone else. Nothing to do with "maven-datanucleus-plugin". The "Q" classes are simply part of the compilation step (or better "pre-compilation")

Comment: I'm using JDK 1.6 and this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Sure but then there is a project at http://datanucleus.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/datanucleus/samples/samples.jdo.query/trunk/  that demonstrates it all, and it works, hence I'd use that to work out what you have different